# Wrapping A Long List of Parameters as a Single Object

Tags: c#

Consider the following interface:

```
public interface SomeRepo
{
    public IEnumerable<IThings> GetThingsByParameters(DateTime startDate,
        DateTime endDate,
        IEnumerable<int> categorIds,
        IEnumerable<int> userIds,
        IEnumerable<int> typeIds,
        string someStringToFilerBy);
}
```

Is there any benefit in doing this instead?

```
public IEnuemrable<IThings> GetThingsByParamters(IParameter parameter);
```

Where `IParameter` is an object defined as such:

```
public interface IParameter
{
    DateTime startDate { get; }
    DateTime endDate { get; }
    IEnumerable<int> categorIds { get; }
    IEnumerable<int> userIds { get; }
    IEnumerable<int> typeIds { get; }
    string someStringToFilerBy { get; }
}
```

I don't see any benefit in doing `IParameter` other than it makes it a bit more readable but the extra layer of complexity doesn't seem to be worth it.

Anything that I maybe missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's just for that single place, it may not be worth it all that much.

Creating a class on its own does have some *possible* benefits, but they're quite dependent on exactly that; whether you would be able to reuse it.

You could add some sort of early data validation to your `IParameters` implementation (eg. `endDate` can't be earlier than `startDate` - it's common sense, you don't need to be a repository object to know that).

If some values are optional and some are not, a `Parameters` class gives you an opportunity to clearly distinguish these two categories.

It's much easier to find all usages of `Parameters` in your code than all the occurences of raw "start date / end date / ids" packs.

This being said, readability isn't a minor concern. I feel that 6 parameters per method is twice too many. And based off experience, I wouldn't bet it will stop at 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in book Clean Code (Robert C. Martin) that is not a good idea to use many parameters in a method (the book recommends use at most 3), if you have a method that requires so many parameters you have to think again on your design, or it suggests that your model need one more class.

Answer (score 0):

The extreme of that is developing your own expression system where `IParameter` has a string operator (`"Equals"`, `"LessThanOrEqualTo"`, `"Plus"`, etc.) and then has an array of `IParameter[]` called `Children` or something.  Of course if you're going to do that, why not use something built-in like LINQ or C#'s `Expression`'s?  If this isn't backed by a database and you need to use string filtering that's a good option (or use a `DataTable`'s built-in filtering/parsing of expressions if you don't care about performance).

If this is backed by a database, usually it's a bad idea to expose arbitrary querying on a repository that, say, ties to a SQL database because the end developer may not know which columns are indexed and may write ill-performant queries (particularly if they don't have easy access to production-scale data) - it's better to give specific query methods that take in specific methods that map to essentially a SQL `SELECT` and fine-tuning each query (assuming your repository is backed by a SQL database).

This is more performant because now you explicitly control which indexes the end developer can query from by exposing a method that takes in explicit arguments.

This also makes unit-testing dependencies of your repository much easier because it's easy to mock repository a strongly typed method like that - you'd end up making a fake in-memory abstraction of the database using LINQ-to-Objects if you allow your services to define their own queries - and that can sometimes give false positives.

There's nothing inherently absolutely wrong - I just see the typical use case for something like that of being very explicit if backed by a database or if not leveraging an already-existing filtering/expression system if this is all in-memory.